# OsError could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate

Tags: python, postgresql, pip, oserror

## What I Use

I use `Windows 11`  and my python version is *3.8* and My **IDE** is `Visual Studio Code`

## Error

There was A problem with my postgresql and I Uninstalled version 14 and Installed version 13

So, When I cloned `Odoo` 15 into my `Odoo` folder

and I was trying to do this command `pip install -r requirements.txt`

and this Error Popped Up:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt
```

and this Popped Up also when I tried to do any pip command in any directory